# ImportError: No module named _winreg, Installing pypiwin32==219 on MacOS X

Tags: python

I am trying to install `pypiwin32==219` in my virtual environment from a requirements.txt file.
 
**requirements.txt**

```
pypiwin32==219
```

I have setup a virtualenv `denv` in which I am working.

```
(denv) Nehas-MacBook-Pro:dash_pdf neha$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I got this traceback error:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/_y/g09fpxn13xq7z6ptmq3095dm0000gn/T/pip-install-7zp59n5n/pypiwin32/setup.py", line 121
    print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
                           ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Building pywin32", pywin32_version)?
```

which really is a python version issue so I switched to the command:

```
(denv) Nehas-MacBook-Pro:dash_pdf neha$ pip2 install -r requirements.txt
```

upon which I get this traceback error:

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/ca/5c086c18de8f70222787b3e824e755b68d99272531522e77bb381d4f60c8/pypiwin32-219.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/_y/g09fpxn13xq7z6ptmq3095dm0000gn/T/pip-install-KEpN56/pypiwin32/setup.py", line 83, in <module>
    import _winreg
ImportError: No module named _winreg
```

I googled some and I found that `_winreg` required Windows. No way I can get `pypiwin32==219` to work on MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

The entire `pypiwin32` module requires Windows. It is, after all, the [Win32 API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) bindings for Python – *none* of it would be usable on anything that isn't Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried installing a VM with Windows to get around this problem but that just kills my computer. Looks like I have reached a dead-end.